# Google Takeout file formats

Tags: gmail, mbox

Does anybody know the file format specifications of Google Takeout exports?

I see that the GMail export *.mbox file can be read by Thunderbird, so I guess the spec is publicly available?

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 1):

The [didenko / mboxrd](https://github.com/didenko/mboxrd) GitHub says that Google Takeout uses the `mboxrd` format:

> Based on experimentation it looks like Google uses the *mboxrd* dialect of *mbox* format with CRLF lines as discussed at the [Wikipedia mbox article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Family)

Looking through my own Google Takeout .mbox file, this seems correct. For instance, the `.mbox` file contains:

```
Hello,

>From the limited error message, it appears that one or more of the files
you are dragging/dropping into Meshroom are not images.
You will need to provide a lot more details, such as the Command Line
window output (if there is any), and log files.
```

while the Gmail web interface displays:

```
Hello,

From the limited error message, it appears that one or more of the files you are dragging/dropping into Meshroom are not images.
You will need to provide a lot more details, such as the Command Line window output (if there is any), and log files.
```

The `.mbox` file has:

```
work and interaction with the community.

>>From today till June 7th is "community bonding period". Xingyu and Tirth
have already been contributing for a little while, but please do give them
```

while the Gmail web interface displays:

```
work and interaction with the community.

>From today till June 7th is "community bonding period". Xingyu and Tirth
have already been contributing for a little while, but please do give them
```

(So this was likely mangled at some other point in the mailing list chain, and Google is still adding an extra `>` according to `mboxrd` rules.)